# Personalização de JQuery Custombox

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, lightbox

Fala galera,

Encontrei um plugin muito bom para lightbox que funciona com as janelas modais do Bootstrap 3.

A documentação é limitada e pode ser encontrada em http://dixso.github.io/custombox/

O que eu preciso é entender como é que aplico o plugin para fazer a Modal abrir no carregamento da página.

Estou usando os exemplos da página, sem mudar nada, nem os ID. Mas só consigo abrir as Modais com cliques, não consegui abrir automaticamente.

Alguém me ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No JavaScript com [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) utilize `$(document).ready` que ao carregar a página, executa o **Modal**.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Custombox.open({
        target: '#modal',
        effect: 'fadein'
      });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal-demo">
    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="Custombox.close();">
        <span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="title">Modal title</h4>
    <div class="text">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 Custombox.open({
        target: '#modal',
        effect: 'fadein'
      });
});
```

```css
/*
 ----------------------------
 Demo
 ----------------------------
 */
iframe {
    border: none;
}
.page-header {
    margin-top: 0;
}
h1, h2, h4 {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
}
h1 > em {
    color: #fc5e5e;
    font-style: normal;
}
#version {
    float: left;
    margin: 37px 0 0 10px;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    clear: both;
}
h4 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
h4 > em {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.share-github {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.demo-content > h4 {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.modal-demo {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 600px;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}
.title {
    padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: #CCC solid 1px;
}
.text {
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
.bs-callout {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.bs-callout > h4,
.bs-callout-support {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.bs-callout:not(.bs-callout-support) > p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.bs-callout-info {
    border-left-color: #D9EDF7;
}
#forkme {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
#custompopover {
    min-width: 330px;
    max-width: 330px;
}
.table-popover:not(.table-methods) > tbody > tr:hover td {
    background-color: #D9EDF7;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.table-demo > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1){
    width: 20%;
}
.table-demo > thead > tr > th:nth-child(2),
.table-demo > thead > tr > th:nth-child(3) {
    width: 15%;
}
.table-popover td span {
    margin-top: 4px;
}
.footer {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.download {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#gitfork {
    display: none;
}
.tab-content-demo {
    overflow: auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #forkme,
    #custompopover {
        display: none;
    }
    #gitfork {
        display: block;
    }
}
.modal-demo .infinite {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 45px;
}

/*
 *  Usage:
 *
 *    <div class="sk-wandering-cubes">
 *      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
 *      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
 *    </div>
 *
 */
.sk-wandering-cubes {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: relative; }
.sk-wandering-cubes .sk-cube {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: sk-wanderingCubeMove 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-wanderingCubeMove 1.8s infinite ease-in-out; }
.sk-wandering-cubes .sk-cube2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
    animation-delay: -0.9s; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-wanderingCubeMove {
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5);
        transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5); }
    50% {
        /* Hack to make FF rotate in the right direction */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-179deg);
        transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-179deg); }
    50.1% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg);
        transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg); }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5);
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5); }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg); } }

@keyframes sk-wanderingCubeMove {
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5);
        transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5); }
    50% {
        /* Hack to make FF rotate in the right direction */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-179deg);
        transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-179deg); }
    50.1% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg);
        transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg); }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5);
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5); }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg); } }

div.sk-wandering-cubes .sk-cube {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://dixso.github.io/custombox/dist/custombox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://dixso.github.io/custombox/dist/custombox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal-demo">
    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="Custombox.close();">
        <span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="title">Modal title</h4>
    <div class="text">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio. O trecho em questão
`
$(document).ready(function(){
 Custombox.open({
        target: '#modal',
        effect: 'fadein'
      });
});
`

Fez o que eu precisava

Mas continuo sem saber como formatar meus coments... sorry.